# Address Module 8.x-1.3

Tags: commerce, composer, 8

I am trying to run address field on my web page, but I get an error

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

So I checked the logs and get

> Error: Class 'CommerceGuys\Addressing\LocaleHelper' not found in Drupal\address\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\AddressDefaultFormatter->getValues() (line 286 of /var/www/mywebsite/modules/contrib/address/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/AddressDefaultFormatter.php)

I checked my composer.json file and have the following required

```
 "drupal/address": "~1.0",
 "commerceguys/addressing": "1.x-dev",
```

ran

```
 composer update drupal/address --with-dependencies
```

from https://www.drupal.org/project/address
but still getting the same error, I believe the error is commerceguys/addressing, but composer update says there is nothing to be updated. Any directions to my problem will help a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have deleted

```
"commerceguys/addressing": "1.x-dev",
```

and reran

```
composer update drupal/address --with-dependencies
```

and it works now. I had a unstable beta and commerceguys came out with a stable version that updated their code.

Comment: You shouldn't need both. If you composer require drupal/address, it should pull its dependencies in.